# Unreachable command in a shell script code while installing Oh My Zsh

Tags: bash, shell, oh-my-zsh

Here is my **sample1.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
echo "foo"
```

Output:

[image]

Here is my **sample2.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf ~/.oh-my-zsh
rm ~/.zshrc

sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
echo "foo"
```

Output:

[image]

As you see, the only difference between above snippets are below lines:

```
rm -rf ~/.oh-my-zsh
rm ~/.zshrc
```

**Question:** why am I able to see **foo**, **only** when OMZ is already installed? What's so specific inside https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh, that after it detects that OMZ does not exist and can be installed, after successful installation, it doesn't continue to reach my *foo*?

Obviously, that `echo "foo"` was just an example to highlight the general problem.

In the final built of the script, what I want to achieve is to simply enable some plugins once OMZ is installed by calling:

`sed -i '' -e 's/^plugins=.*/plugins=(git, sublime)/' ~/.zshrc`

This line works fine only when I trigger it manually. The problem is that it never calls `sed` once OMZ is installed. Thanks for pointing out, where is the problem that I don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the install script for OMZ is to switch the current shell to sh with the line `env zsh`. I believe that this is basically causing your script to fork ZSH and never actually finish running. If you `exit` from the ZSH shell then it should continue as normal.

Comment: Thanks for that. Indeed `exit` allows the rest of the script to be triggered, however that works only when `exit` will be provided manually, which isn't what I originally wanted. My workaround of this issue was to simply extract everything after OMZ installation into separate file. Vote up for efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Oh-my-zsh will fork the current process.  To fix, just cut it out of the script.

```
 sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh | sed "s/env zsh//g")"
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use `&` and `wait` to run the install command in parallel and wait for its completion.

```sh
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)" &
wait
echo "foo"
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @mgild for the idea, that was exactly what I was looking for. Just one thing - the command should be:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh | sed "s/env zsh.*//g")"
```

So that sed removes the whole and not just "env zsh" substring.